# How to catch oozie spark output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, oozie

Is there anyway to catch an output from spark then input it on a shell? We're currently using scala to create jar files and want our spark output to be a shell input.
My idea is to use ${wf:actionData('spark-XXXX')['var']} i just dont know how to implement it in spark. So basically, my problem is how to output a key=value pair from spark in oozie.

Comment: RTFM -- the Spark action does not support `<capture-output>`, at least in the current version of Oozie (V4.3); just compare the latest XML schemas for Spark https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html and Java actions https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#Oozie_Schema_Version_0.5

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `sprak` job in `shell action` and use `spark submit` from the shell script. `shell action` supports `<capture-output>` option, so you can just print the variable to console: `variable_name=value`.

Then, as a parameter to another action `${wf:actionData('shell_action_name')['variable_name']}`

I know this is not so 'clean', but will work and you can achieve the same things as with `spark action`

Comment: It will work **_if_** the shell has access to all the necessary Spark libs, Spark configuration and Spark shell scripts such as `spark-submit`. That's not trivial to set up, in the general case where Spark is not installed on the worker nodes.

Comment: Also, the shell would have to make sure that no junk message makes it to `stdout` -- the `<capture-output>` feature will fail if it collects more than 2048 bytes, and crash the workflow.

Comment: Yes, you need to have spark installed on yarn nodes, but having all dependencies in oozie action scope is not hard to achieve. And yes, you need to control output to not exceed the buffer - also not hard to assure, just log you application logs into file.

Comment: ...but this kind of caveats and warnings make the difference between vague answers and _great_ answers, that may attract upvotes over time...   : )