# Use class variables inside Oozie workflow

Tags: scala, oozie, oozie-workflow

I have an oozie workflow that has the following format:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="${componente}">
...
    <start to="S000_Guida_rilevazioni_annuali"/>
    <action name="action name 1" cred="hcat,hs2-creds">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>${master}</master>
            <mode>cluster</mode>
            <name>class 1 name</name>
            <class>com.sample.project</class>
            <jar>${wf_path}/jar_file.jar</jar>
            <spark-opts>--queue ${queueName} --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 2G --jars ${hiveWarehouseConnectorLib}</spark-opts>
        </spark>
        <ok to="action name 2" />
        <error to="killJobAction"/>
    </action>
...
```

This workflow has a decision implemented that if goes into error, then it runs an action called killJobAction.

Now what I want to implement is to change the code flow based on value of a variable inside the scala class. Let say a boolean variable call varWF=true/false. Is it possible?

Comment: Can someone help me to make this question more clear(if it is not...)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your spark job in *shell action* and use *spark submit* from the shell script. [How to catch oozie spark output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154474/how-to-catch-oozie-spark-output/)

And use this capture in Oozie decision Node https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.4_Decision_Control_Node

for example

```
<workflow-app name="foo-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    ...
    <decision name="mydecision">
        <switch>
            <case to="next-action1">
             ${wf:actionData('shell_action_name')['variable_name'] eq 'true'}
            </case>
            <default to="next-action2"/>
        </switch>
    </decision>
    ...
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: unfortunately I dont have access to spark-submit, but thanks for the answer and like to other question